# Comments in _CoqProject

Tags: comments, coq

Is there a way to have comments in a `_CoqProject` file?

I'd like to compile **only part of a library**, without completely removing all the other files from the `_CoqProject` file.

Comment: Could you try if prefixing `#` symbol works?

Comment: That works, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#` is treated as a comment-the-rest-of-the-line symbol.

I think it is not documented as of now (see [issue #7647](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/7647)). But the [source code](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/00a01f65be79bef8592928941646750968dbe648/lib/coqProject_file.ml4#L107) and some experiments show that it works.

Comment: I think `coq_makefile` should be modified to print this information as a result to `-h`